# How to get click of buttons inside balloons in android google map v2?

Tags: android

I am working on GoogleMap V2 in Android, I have some Markers on the map, clicking on any marker I am opening InfoWindow. In my info window I have 4 textview and 2 buttons. I want to perform some different action clicking on these two buttons: In my case button 1 is for get direction and button2 is for make a phone call. I have no idea how can I do this so please help me to find the solution of this problem. For better understanding I attached an image of my infowindow. Below are the some code which I tried to fire my intents:

```
phoneBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"
                            + phoneText.getText().toString()));
                    System.out.println("Clicking");
                    activity.startActivity(callIntent);
                }
            });
```

[image]

Comment: Just setOnClickListener on that button which is present inside the inflator used in popup window.

Comment: In My question I have do this.

Comment: @Shiv i don' think it is possible. check the answer below

Answer (score 4):

Quoting form the docs

**Info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events**. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described below.

**Info window is not a live View, rather the view is rendered as an image onto the map. As a result, any listeners you set on the view are disregarded and you cannot distinguish between click events on various parts of the view. You are advised not to place interactive components — such as buttons, checkboxes, or text inputs — within your custom info window.**

You can use an OnInfoWindowClickListener to listen to click events on an info window. To set this listener on the map, call GoogleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(OnInfoWindowClickListener). When a user clicks on an info window, onInfoWindowClick(Marker) will be called and the info window will be highlighted in the default highlight color (Holo Blue for devices running Ice Cream Sandwich and newer, orange for earlier versions of Android).

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener